# Is the Electroweak theory chiral regardless of temperature?

Tags: electroweak, weak-interaction

Is the electroweak theory a chiral theory regardless of whether one is above the electroweak symmetry breaking temperature or not?

Comment: Yes, it breaks chiral symmetry explicitly and thus this symmetry is never restored at high-energy

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the SM is chiral regardless of temperature. Parity is broken explicitly (not spontaneously) and thus this symmetry is never restored at high temperatures.

There are howere left-right symmetric extensions of the SM, in which parity is indeed broken spontaneously at low energies and would be restored at high temperature.